# Gui cli boot arch

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, grub, gui

I am using arch with xserver, and as bootmanager grub. Is it possible to create entries to use first one for boot option cli and second entry as gui boot option? I will do a kind of dual boot for gui/cli

Comment: Gnome is a Desktop Environment (DE), it has nothing to do with a bootmanager. Your question makes no sense whatsoever. If you don't want to start Gnome, either log into a TTY or use a different entry in whatever does manage your boot to log into `multi-user.target`.

Comment: Sorry it is late, what I mean is not gnome, its grub

Comment: @jason’s comment is still valid:  it doesn’t make much sense to have a boot option  to choose between CLI and GUI for the same operating system.

Comment: Of course it makes sense, and some distributions even have set up their default grub configuration like that. It's entirely reasonable to have a boot-time choice of where you want to end up.

Comment: @MichaelHomer and the expectation with Arch is that you are able to configure grub yourself to acheive that.

Comment: Seems like a good reason to ask a question about it on this site, eh.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am here to ask. Does anyone know, how to configure grub like this or can show me an example(I only know 40_custom) . And second yes, it make sense, for configuration  like grub or network, I want it like plug and play (easy), I don't need GUI and for work, stuff like email and office, I need GUI

Answer (score 0):

In the past you could select the *runlevel* to boot up to. With systemd you must now specify the wanted target. Typically, the default target is `graphical.target` with the GUI login.  The cli target is probably `multi-user.target`. See systemd's man page [man bootup](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html) (the ascii-art looks better in a terminal with monospaced font).

You can select which target you want to boot to on the kernel command line with option `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`, for example.